# can't run a script from Matlab console

Tags: matlab, shell

Having a script called  - `scriptForGragh` which contains the follow comands   -

```
figure(1) ;
hold on;
stem(F);
plot(FV);
```

`FV` and `F` are variants which defined before  .

I run from the shell -

`>> run(scriptForGragh)`

But it prompts -

```
??? Undefined function or variable
'scriptForGragh'.
```

I checked the Current Folder of the shell and it was on the currect path .

What is wrong here ?

**Edit:**

solution - just run `scriptForGragh.m`

Answer (score 0):

To run something in matlab normally you don`t need to do run. Just type the name of your function. If you create a script be sure to set your current path on this application.

Just by typing help run in matlab command window you will have more detail about it.

Comment: Be sure to do the `cd` or `addpath`. And did scriptForGragh is the right name ? it`s not scriptForGraph ? With "p"

Comment: I checked the `cd`  - it's OK  . also the name is OK (my typo)

Comment: It just because you made a typo or because your script is not visible. If you type script and do tab did your script name appear ? Because it not an `??? Undefined function or variable 'F'.` but a function problem you have.

Comment: hhhaaa ... It's because there was no `.m` at its suffix . 
`scriptForGragh` - didn't work  . `scriptForGragh.m`  - work  .
Thanks .

Comment: sound strang. You`re not suppose to do that, but if it work great for you :)

Comment: Maybe in advanced version it not needed  . I use R2010a version .